# Find first element after text

Tags: jquery

How can I create a selector with jQuery so I can get hold of the phone number in an html like this:

```
<div class="contact">
  This is the contact info:
  Address: <b>Elm Street</b>
  Phone: <b>911</b>
  Email: <b>info@example</b>
</div>
```

And unfortunately, I'm not in control of the html, and the phone number is not always in the second b-element inside the contact-div, it may be the first or the third also.

How is it possible to get the first b-element after the text "Phone:"?

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: Do you have control over how this HTML is formatted/structured?

Comment: You might be better to just get the text of the contact element (without the HTML) and parse it, maybe with a regular expression

Comment: Since you are not aware of the occurence of the phone element, you're better off giving a class to your phone bold tag to distinguish it from the other ones.

Comment: @chazsolo and also DinoMyte, I'm not in control of the html. Should have mentioned that, will edit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Another way is way is use `contents()` and filter the text nodes to get "Phone" text node then use `next()` for the `<b>`

```js
const phoneNum = $('.contact').contents().filter(function(){
   return this.nodeType === 3 && this.textContent.includes('Phone')
}).next().text()

console.log('Phone=', phoneNum)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact">
  This is the contact info:
  Address: <b>Elm Street</b>
  Phone: <b>911</b>
  Email: <b>info@example</b>
</div>
<hr/>
Result: <div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

> How is it possible to get the first b-element after the text "Phone:"?

You can

- get the html text with `.html()`
- `.split()` the html on "Phone:"
- convert the remaining html back to a jquery object
- use `.find()`

Might be just as easy to use a regex on the `.text()` directly.

```js
var txt = $(".contact").html();
var part = txt.split("Phone:")[1];
var html = $("<div></div>").html(part);
var phone = html.find("b").first().text();
$("#result").text(phone);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact">
  This is the contact info:
  Address: <b>Elm Street</b>
  Phone: <b>911</b>
  Email: <b>info@example</b>
</div>
<hr/>
Result: <div id='result'></div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You could read the text content of the '.contact' div with the [`jQuery.text()`](https://api.jquery.com/text/) function, then you can compute the starting and ending index of the first word after the 'Phone: ' string with the [`indexOf`](https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_indexof.asp) function. Finally, the phone will be the substring between these two indexes.

```js
$(function() {
  let contact = $('.contact').text();
  let phoneString = 'Phone: ';
  let phoneStartIndex = contact.indexOf(phoneString) + phoneString.length;
  let phoneEndIndex = contact.substr(phoneStartIndex).indexOf(' ');
  let phone = contact.substr(phoneStartIndex, phoneEndIndex);
  console.log(phone);
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="contact">
  This is the contact info: Address: <b>Elm Street</b> Phone: <b>911</b> Email: <b>info@example</b>
</div>
```